# Обратный перебор вектора с size_t

Tags: c++

Как мы знаем для перебора вектора / массива лучше использовать переменную типа size_t. Но когда нужно перебирать в обратном порядке возникает проблема.

```
for (size_t i = size - 1; i >= 0; i--) cout << a[i];
```

Когда i дойдет до нуля, произойдет переполнение. Мой знакомый предложил простой способ решения проблемы.

```
for (size_t i = size; i > 0; i--) cout << a[i - 1];
```

Но как-то некрасиво выходит, все-таки i - 1 а обращаемся к элементу i. Так вот вопрос, что лучше, использовать size_t как показано выше или использовать int?

```
for (int i = (int)size - 1; i >= 0; i--) cout << a[i];
```

Comment: А обратный итератор с range-for не подойдет?

Comment: @VladimirGamalian как Вы себе это представляете?

Comment: @alexolut смутно, что-то типа адаптера, разворачивающего итератор, во, вот так: `for (auto i : boost::adaptors::reverse(vec)) {}`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Для перебора вектора лучше использовать итератор. В случае работы задом наперед, подойдет реверсный итератор:

```
for(auto i=a.rbegin();i!=a.rend();++i)
{
}
```

Но если хочется использовать индекс - нет проблем:

```
for(size_t i=a.size();i--;)
{
}
```

Работает эта штука так - на каждой итерации она сначала проверяет, что i не ноль, после этого делает декремент и идет в тело цикла. В цикле получаются правильные индексы. После последней итерации, будет 0--, и i станет равна 2^( sizeof(size_t)*8 ) - 1, но нам это будет безразлично.

Замечу, что в случае такой работы с массивом перестанут работать некоторые оптимизации, например, векторизация или раскрутка цикла.

Answer (score 3):

Как ни странно:

```
for (size_t i = size - 1; i != -1; i--) cout << a[i];
```

Если будет `warning`:

```
for (size_t i = size - 1; i != size_t(-1); i--) cout << a[i];
```

Comment: Ворнинг же будет на сравнение знаковых с безнаковыми.

Comment: @Vladimir Gamalian у меня студия не ругнулась. Но на всякий случай поправил ответ

Comment: `gcc -Wall` ругался (без приведения к `size_t`), ну и для гурманов, вместо приведения в си стиле `size_t(-1)`, можно использовать `std::numeric_limits<size_t>::max()`.

Comment: Тогда уж `static_cast<size_t>(-1)`, `numeric_limits` как-то не к месту.

Comment: тоже вариант, если гурман не жосткий противник кастинга )